# How to deploy laravel nextjs application in aws

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created the application with `laravel` as backend/api and `nextjs` as frontend, my directory structure is like

```
root
  --frontend --> production build code after npm run build (standalone folder)
  --backend --> laravel code for apis
```

i have tried to upload these things to deploy in `elasticbeanstalk` with `node` installed,
the application is fine with the `laravel` code, it is running as expected, but when i tries to run the `nextjs` app with calling `serverjs` inside the project, it is failing

when i start the `serverjs` it started successfully, but when i tries to open it with `port 3000` it keeps loading, page doesn't load,

so, what is the better way to deploy the both application in same `elasticbeanstalk` and what should be the project file structure?